# When does an export break static module resolution in ES6/2015

Tags: javascript, module, static, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code.

```js
//------ lib.js ------
export const willThisBreakStaticModuleResolution = {iAm: 'a literal object'};

export default function() {...}

//------ main.js ------
import { willThisBreakStatic } from 'lib.js';
...
```

Would the named export in lib.js break static module resolution, or does that only happen if an object were exported as default?

**Update**

By "break static resolution", I mean if all other modules in the "system" would then also be resolved dynamically at runtime instead of statically at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the named export in lib.js break static module resolution, or does that only happen if an object were exported as default?

You seem to assume that the named exports become somehow "properties" of the default export. That's not the case (*) so this does not impact static resolution.

The exports of a module are described through `ExportEntry`s and there will be an entry for each named export as well as the default export.

The [spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-source-text-module-records) has examples for the different `export` declarations.

---

*: Of course transpilers might currently do this to simulate modules with ES5 syntax, but that's a limitation of the the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then, would it break static resolution or not?

Comment: But this would?
`export const myFunc = function() {...}
 export default { afunction: myfunc }`

Comment: No, why? Maybe it's not clear to me what you mean by "break static resolution".

Comment: Because if this is imported in, say, module2: `import funcs from `module1`, then `funcs.anotherFunc = function() {...}` would make this work in module3 importing funcs from module1: `funcs.anotherFunc() // works!!!`.

Comment: Ah. I think I misunderstood your question then. Yes, if something exports an object, and that object is mutated, everything else that imports the module will also see the mutated object. That's how objects work, modules don't change that.

Comment: Yes, of course. So any export that potentially can be mutated would remove static compilation benefits? I wonder if that still holds up with an `Object.freeze()`.

Comment: *"So any export that potentially can be mutated would remove static compilation benefits?"* The point of ES6 modules is that it's possible to statically determine the dependencies. That is not affected by the type of value that is exported.

Comment: "You may be wondering – why do we need named exports if we could simply default-export objects (like CommonJS)? The answer is that you can’t enforce a static structure via objects and lose all of the associated advantages" Source: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: Well, yeah, default exporting an object is not the same as having named exports. If you use an object instead of named exports where you should be using named exports, then you are doing something wrong. But that doesn't make exporting objects a bad thing. I think I still don't see the point of the question.